# LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 ->BeginScene() function failed

Tags: c++, algorithm, directx

Now, I try to implement an engine for game 2D.
I have create window for game successful.
But there is a prolem. When I call  **device->BeginScene()** it did't work. that function failed.

I have searched and knowed that function fail because I already have called **device->BeginScene()** before and didn't call **device->EndScene()**.( That mean I call function  **device->BeginScene()** two times continuously).
some code:

```
//GameEngine.cpp
    void CGameEngine::Draw() 
        {
            // let the state draw the screen
            if (!states.empty())
            {
                this->RenderStart();// this function failed- return 0
                this->Render2D_Start();
                states.back()->Draw(this);
                this->Render2D_Stop();
                this->RenderStop();

            }
        }
```

I have debuged many times but not found what is wrong!!

Can anyone help me??

( All class in engine are OK, problem only on class CIntroState and CGameEngine)
download my project at: http://mediafire.com/?h3jumchcqujnh69

Thank in advance.
Sory for poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174350%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? It specifies that you are not allowed to nest BeginScene calls. You must call `EndScene` after `BeginScene`, before calling `BeginScene` again.

> There should be one IDirect3DDevice9::BeginScene/IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene pair between any successive calls to present (either IDirect3DDevice9::Present or IDirect3DSwapChain9::Present). IDirect3DDevice9::BeginScene **should be called once** before any rendering is performed, and IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene **should be called once** after all rendering for a frame has been submitted to the runtime. Multiple non-nested IDirect3DDevice9::BeginScene/IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene pairs between calls to present are legal, but having more than one pair may incur a performance hit.